# How do I put a single byte into network byte order?

Tags: c, network-programming, byte, network-protocols, bit

So I have variables:

```
uint8_t version = 1;
uint8_t ttl = 1;
uint16_t payload_length = 
uint32_t account_identifier = 24027;
uint32_t source_address = 0;
uint32_t destination_address = 0;
uint16_t checksum = 0;
uint16_t protocol = 1;
```

I want to make all values in network byte order.

I know to use `htons()` for the 16-bit values and `htonl()` for the 32-bit values.

So I would do: `uint32_t source_address = htonl(0);` and `uint16_t checksum = htons(0);`

What should I use for the 8-bit values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should I use for the 8 bit values?

Nothing. There is no "endianness" for 1-byte (8-bit) values. So you don't have to worry about them (which is why there's not `hton` function for them).

Comment: What about the bit endianness in a byte,is it going to be MSB0 or LSB0. note that bigendian systems have both representations

Comment: @bare_metal: you cannot address a single bit in your code. [Bit endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#.22Bit_endianness.22) generally only applies to physical transmission over a serial medium, and in those cases is directly handled by the protocol and hardware itself (i.e. 802.3 and 802.11). As far as C code is concerned, there is no bit endianness, since you can't address a single bit. Endianness is a matter of how bytes are packed and addressed; if you can't address it, it has no endianness. Since you can't address bits, there's effectively no bit-level endianness.

Comment: lets assume we trasfer a byte from a big endian machine to another big endian machine and consider one has an MSB0 bit representation and another one has an LSB0 bit representation how is this handled? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering). and RFC recommended style is MSB0

Comment: @bare_metal: it is handled in the protocol. For example, look at the [802.3 (Ethernet) frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame). It is defined in sets of *octets*. [In the Ethernet protocol, the bytes are arranged in big-endian order, but the octet bits are little-endian](http://www.infocellar.com/networks/ethernet/frame.htm). So when the two computers transfer data, their network cards must arrange the bits in the order that the protocol requires. The network hardware handles this bit-level endianness for you so that your code and CPU don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

8 bit values have just one byte, so it doesen't really matter in which byte ordering they are - they will be the same. So use nothing :).

Comment: ahh ok I see, makes sense now. Thanks for the replies all!

Answer (score 0):

> What should I use for the 8-bit values.

Nothing. You can't put one byte into order.